# Haskell: simple way to read a line containing Int and Float?

Tags: haskell

I want to read lines from a file that looks like this:

```
1 2.1
2 2.2
3 2.3
```

It's a simple an Int and a Float on each line

This is what I came up with, to read each line:

```
readFoo :: String -> (Int, Float)
readFoo line = (read (splitOn " " line !! 0), read (splitOn " " line !! 1))
```

Or I also made a datatype, and then the `read` part is simple.

```
data Foo = Foo Int Float deriving (Show, Read)
getM (Foo m p) = m
getP (Foo m p) = p

readFoo :: String -> Foo
readFoo line = read $ "Foo " ++ line :: Foo
```

But there must be a simpler way to do this, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One neat way to express this is using the [`ViewPatterns`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns) extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

readFoo :: String -> (Int, Float)
readFoo (words -> [read -> i, read -> f]) = (i ,f)
```

Another way to write it in standard Haskell would be e.g.

```
readFoo :: String -> (Int, Float)
readFoo ln = (read i, read f) where
    [i, f] = words ln
```

Of course, all this assumes that you don't care about error handling.

Comment: I was actually looking for a standard way to do it, so the second code snippet was exactly what I needed - thank you.

Comment: You could write `(i:f:_) = words ln` and it won't die if the line has more than two words.